# How the router works for 2 controllers?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following in the routes where `controllers` is of the `Home` controller where as `crud` is to make generic crud operation for every models.

```
var controllers = require('../controllers/home');
var Home = require('../models/home');
var crud = require('../controllers/crud')(Home, ['name', 'location', 'company'], ['company']);

router.get('/', crud.RetrieveList, controllers.Index);
```

How does the router calls these 2 controllers ?

Answer (score 0):

Router calls handlers as pipeline. Params after `'/'` should be a handlers that take 3 params (request, response, next handler), and next handler calls only if previous handler calls it.

Sample:

```js
// First request handler.
const handler1 = (req, res, next) => {
  // Check if we have `?do_error=1` in requested URL.
  if (req.query.do_error === '1') {
    return res.send('Error by first handler.');
  }
  
  // Go next handler (if not returned with error).
  next();
}

// Second request handler.
const handler2 = (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Message by second handler.');
}

// Init route.
router.get('/', handler1, handler2);
```